# preposition+being+past particle

Tags: grammar

Please explain me the meaning and usage of "being+past particle" when we use with "preposition" ?

I don't know what kind of meanings it would conveys

1)
She was afraid of being accused of a crime which she did not commit. (What does "being accused of" mean?)

2)
Members must have the ability to organize without being challenged by external government authorities.

Comment: It's active and passive activities. In life and in languages, sometimes we give and sometimes receive. If you give me a gift, I get the gift. Another way to say that is *I was given a gift*. In your example, we don't know who accused her of a crime. All we know is that she was worried about an accusation. She wasn't afraid of accusing (actively) anyone of a crime -- she was afraid of the accusation, *of being accused* (passively).